# Serialize jquery sortable

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, serialization, portlet

I have been digging around on this site and googling for a while now and I cannot find a good solution to my problem. I would like to be able to save the state of my jquery portlets on a page. I would rather not have a "save state" button if I can avoid it.

Anyway, I just have the jquery code copied from their portlet example:

```
$(function() {
    $(".column").sortable({
        connectWith: '.column'
    });

    $(".portlet").addClass("ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-helper-clearfix ui-corner-all")
        .find(".portlet-header")
            .addClass("ui-widget-header ui-corner-all")
            .prepend('<span class="ui-icon ui-icon-minusthick"></span>')
            .end()
        .find(".portlet-content");

    $(".portlet-header .ui-icon").click(function() {
        $(this).toggleClass("ui-icon-minusthick").toggleClass("ui-icon-plusthick");
        $(this).parents(".portlet:first").find(".portlet-content").toggle();
    });

    $(".column").disableSelection();
});
```

I have tried adding `$(".column").serialize()` and `$(".column").sortable('serialize')` and the same as above, but using `$(".portlet")` instead... I created a variable and set it to the value of the serialize method, but it returns nothing. What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Here is the code for column with a portlet inside:

```
 <div class="column" id="column_1">

<div class="portlet" id="portlet_1">

<div class="portlet-header">Times</div>
&nbsp Longest:
<div class="portlet-content">

<ChartFXGauge:DigitalPanel ID="LongestTimePanel" runat="server" >
</ChartFXGauge:DigitalPanel>
<p>
<a href="LongestORTime.aspx">(BySurgeon)</a>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: can you show the markup also or better recreate it at jsfiddle or jsbin

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I ended up solving with this code:

```
$(".column").each(function() {
alert($(this).sortable("toArray"));
});
```

Which serializes each column instead of only the first column.

Comment: I couldn't get "serializable" to work, so I used "toArray" like so, and just passed in the result to my controller. Yay!

Answer (score 2):

you want to use the .toArray() function of sortable.

from the jquery sortable documentation:

> toArray
>
> Signature:
>       .sortable( "toArray" )
>
> Serializes the sortable's item id's
>   into an array of string. If you have
>
> ```
> <ul id="a_sortable"><br>
> <li id="hello">Hello</li><br>
> <li id="goodbye">Good bye</li><br>
> </ul>
> ```
>
> and do
>
> ```
> var result = $('#a_sortable').sortable('toArray');
> ```
>
> then
>
> result[0] will contain "hello" and
>   result[1] will contain "goodbye".

so to be able to save the state, you'll have to have some sort of ajax call for the **change** option that calls the .sortable('toArray')  and you'll have a nice array of the id's in order.

Answer (score 0):

Do your portlets have an id attribute?

From the [docs](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#method-serialize)

> If serialize returns an empty string,
>   make sure the id attributes include an
>   underscore

Comment: Yeah, I saw that. It just returns [object Object] after I add ids with underscores.

Comment: are you debugging this in IE?  you should user firefox with firebug, then write the output to the console like this: console.log(output); 

It will give you a much better look at what exactly it is you are getting back.